# How to bring application focus foreground when run through jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I am using jenkins to run my test suite and when i build it is working fine, but the problem is, i want to bring the application into focus. At present application is running minimized window, though i bring the focus using below method, the application is not coming into focus.

```
public static void focusWindow(String strEmulatorWindowName)
    {
        User32 user32 = User32.instance;  
        HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, strEmulatorWindowName);
        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOW);  
        user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); 
    }
```

Can someone help me how to do this?

I am running jenkins from command prompt and to build i am clicking on build now in the jenkins job.

Comment: Can someone please throw light on this?